# Jenkins get list of builds and parameters

Tags: api, jenkins

I would like to make an API call to Jenkins to fetch a list of builds along with their parameters and status. We currently pass a git commit sha1 as a parameter to build a specific branch. Any ideas how I can get this information easily?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Jenkins provides a nice api.

It is documented at:

```
http://$HOST/jenkins/api
```

You probably want something like:

```
http://$HOST/jenkins/api/xml?xpath=/hudson/job[1]/build[1]/action[1]/parameter&depth=2
```

Comment: It seems as though using a similar query than you showed doesn't actually produce any results after /hudson/job[1].

Comment: Thank you michas. You led me to the correct answer! Here's the output i was looking for. I see you have to specify the exact build number. ```/job/Clinical.Search/15/api/xml```

Comment: You should be able to use `/job/Clinical.Search/lastSuccessfulBuild/api/xml` to get the last successful build as well.

Answer (score 8):

As far as I know, this can't be done in a single API call.

First query all builds.

```
/job/<jobname>/api/xml
/job/<jobname>/api/json
```

This will return xml or json output, respectively.

Once you get the build numbers, you can query each build number.

```
/job/<jobname>/<jobnum>/api/xml?xpath=/freeStyleBuild/action/lastBuiltRevision/SHA
/job/<jobname>/<jobnum>/api/json?tree=actions[lastBuiltRevision[SHA]]
```

Then you can check the SHA in the result against your SHA.

Comment: or one call like this...  ```/job/<job-name>/api/json?tree=builds[actions[parameters[name,value]],result,building,number,duration,estimatedDuration]```

Answer (score 3):

Combining @user1255162 's  comment to an answer.  I had to query set of builds and print its parameter for a report.  Here is the code snippet in groovy

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper


def root = "<url to job>"
def options = "/api/json?tree=builds[actions[parameters[name,value]],result,building,number,duration,estimatedDuration]"

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def text = new URL("${root}/${options}").text
def data = jsonSlurper.parseText(text)

data["builds"].each { buildsdata ->
    def result = buildsdata["result"]
    def num = buildsdata["number"]
    print("${root}/${num}/parameters  |")
    buildsdata["actions"].each { actions ->
        if (actions["_class"].equals("hudson.model.ParametersAction")) {
            actions["parameters"].sort({it.name}).each { param ->
                    print("${param.name}=${param.value}|")
            }
        }
    }
    println("")
}
```